# How can I avoid race condition without using reduction

Tags: c++, c, openmp

```
void mul_pol( my_compl *p1, my_compl * p2, my_compl * pr,int m,int n)
{
int i,j,k;
float s;  
#pragma omp parallel for private(k,pr) schedule (static)
 for ( k =0; k <= m +n ; k ++){
pr[ k ].re=0;
pr[ k ].im=0;
}  



#pragma omp parallel for private(i,j,p1,p2,m,n) schedule (static) 
for ( i =0; i <= m ; i ++)  
for ( j =0; j <= n ; j ++)     
  {

    {
    pr[ i + j ].re += p1[ i ].re* p2[ j ].re;
    pr[ i + j ].re -= p1[ i ].im* p2[ j ].im;
    pr[ i + j ].im += p1[ i ].re* p2[ j ].im;
    pr[ i + j ].im += p1[ i ].im* p2[ j ].re;

  } 
 }  
// #pragma omp barrier  
}
```

In the following program I am getting small exection time but due to race condition output is not accurate. Please can anyone suggest apart from reduction clause how to improve the code. i also tried critical clause as well. Althought results with critical are very poor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the race condition arises from the second loop nest, because different combinations of `i` and `j` have the same sum.  The best way to work around the problem would probably be to eliminate the data race.  There are a few variations on how you might do that, but the ones that come first to mind involve making the outer loop of the second nest run over the indices of `pr`, and the inner one over either the indices of `p1` or those of `p2`.  In that way, each element of `pr` will be modified by exactly one thread.

Because that modification leads to different iterations of the outer loop requiring different amounts of work, you could consider switching to dynamic thread scheduling.  Don't assume that you need dynamic scheduling, however -- the regular way in which the amount of work varies might well make static scheduling balance out over the course of the whole computation.

For example,

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(i,j,p1,p2,m,n)
for (k = 0; k <= m + n; k++) {
    int mini = (k <= n) ? 0 : k - n;
    int maxi = (k <= m) ? k : m;

    for ( i = mini; i <= maxi ; i ++) {
        j = k - i;

        pr[ k ].re += p1[ i ].re* p2[ j ].re;
        // ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, although after modifying code,#pragma omp parallel for private(i,pr) schedule (dynamic) 
  for ( i =0; i <= m ; i ++)  
  #pragma omp parallel for private(j,p1,p2) schedule (dynamic) 
    for ( j =0; j <= n ; j ++), it's not displaying any results.

Comment: #pragma omp parallel for private(i,pr) schedule (static) 
  for ( i =0; i <= m ; i ++)  
  #pragma omp parallel for private(p1) schedule (static) 
    for ( j =0; j <= n ; j ++) I tried dynamic scheduling as well but it's not working with either of them.

Comment: @Pragya, neither of those can be consistent with the modification I suggested.  The outer loop should be over the indices of `pr`, which evidently run from `0` to `m+n`.  One or both bounds of the inner loop will vary for some iterations of the outer one.  I have added code to my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: Thanks a lot John for explanation and code improvement. I really appreciate all your help.